# I have copied one figure file from the Matlab figure editor. I have then pasted it directly into word. what is the extension of the figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I cannot identify the file type of the figure if I directly copy it from the editor and paste it in MS word file. I have erroneously attached all figures in that way. But the journal requires me to paste all figures in .jpeg/pdf/eps format.
Is there any way that I don't have to redo the exercise?[image]

Comment: I've found that copying or "Saving as" in non vector format from the default figure view generally produces results unacceptable for publication quality graphics. I doubt you'll find a way, but let's hope otherwise :)

Comment: Directly pasting into Word is probably going to use Windows Metafile, you might try `paste special` in Word to be able to pick the format that is used.  But you'll need to copy form the original `.fig` first.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your problem has nothing to do with matlab. You can simply extract figure from MS Word. Right-click -> Save image as... Then, whatever format the figure is, convert it to .jpeg and paste it again.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using. The graphics changed from release r2014b. Your answer might make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use the File|Save As in the MATLAB figure viewer to save as pdf, eps, or jpeg?

If you have a lot of figures, then a loop like this might work.

```
ix = 1;
for hx = findall(0, 'type', 'figure')'
  figname = get(hx, 'Name');
  if ~isequal(handles.appName, figname)
    figure(hx);
    figname = ['figure_' num2str(ix) '.jpg'];
    saveas(hx, figname , 'jpg');
  end
end
```

Check the documentation for [saveas](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html?searchHighlight=saveas) for other options. The details appear to be the same for release r2014a with the older graphics.